# Avoid useEffect to run on client side if data exist from server side in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have server side rendered page, on the page load I am fetching the data on server side and passing to the client side components.

So I have created and hook and inside the hook I have a state which gets the data onChange of checkBoxes and when the state is changed I am triggering one useEffect inside the hook which will invoke the API call to fetch the new data on the client and update all the components again. The state is defined as a dependency for useEffect.

**Page**

```
const ProductListPage = (props) => {
  const { setUserAuthToken } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const { setMenuCategories } = useContext(HeaderContext)
  const { userAuthToken, menuCategories, checkoutConfig, productList } =
    props || {}
  const { currencyOptionsBase } = checkoutConfig?.[0] || {}
  const { updateMiniCartTotalsInformation } =
    useUpdateMiniCartTotalsInformation()

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserAuthToken(userAuthToken)
    setMenuCategories(menuCategories)
    const cartId = Cookies.get(AUTH.MASKED_QUOTE_ID)
    if (userAuthToken || cartId) {
      updateMiniCartTotalsInformation()
    }
  }, [
    menuCategories,
    setMenuCategories,
    setUserAuthToken,
    updateMiniCartTotalsInformation,
    userAuthToken,
  ])

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Product List Page</title>
      </Head>
      <ProductListPageProvider>
        <div>
          {productList && (
            <CategoryRoot
              categoryData={productList}
              currencyCode={currencyOptionsBase}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </ProductListPageProvider>
    </>
  )
}

// TODO: Once NextMainLayout is moved inside _app.js this line
//  should be removed as it will be the default MainLayout
ProductListPage.Layout = NextMainLayout

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    let userAuthToken = null

    const { storeCode, countryCode, languageCode } = commonUtils.getStoreConfig(
      context.locale
    )
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo(context.locale)
    const { sessionId } = getCookieFromServer(context.req.headers.cookie)
    const { fetchUrlParams } = getUrlParams(context.query)
    const { genderParam, slugPath, isBrands } = createUrl(
      context?.params?.slug,
      context?.params?.param
    )
    const isGlopal = context?.req?.headers['x-glopal'] === '1'
    const glopalStoreId =
      context?.req?.headers['x-glopal-country']?.toLowerCase()
    if (sessionId && typeof sessionId === 'string') {
      userAuthToken = await loginByCookie(apolloClient, storeCode, sessionId)
    }

    const promiseProductList = getProductList(
      apolloClient,
      isGlopal ? glopalStoreId : countryCode,
      languageCode,
      isBrands ? slugPath : `${context?.params?.slug}/${slugPath}`,
      PAGE_COUNT, // page number to fetch initial data
      fetchUrlParams(),
      genderParam,
      PRODUCT_COUNT
    )
    const promiseMenuCategories = getMenuCategories(
      apolloClient,
      countryCode,
      languageCode
    )

    const promiseCheckoutConfig = getCheckoutConfig(apolloClient, storeCode)

    const promises = [
      promiseMenuCategories,
      promiseProductList,
      promiseCheckoutConfig,
    ]

    const [menuCategories, productList, checkoutConfig] = await Promise.all(
      promises
    )

    // if no category information is found
    // we need to redirect the user to a 404 page
    if (!productList) {
      return {
        notFound: true,
      }
    }
    return {
      props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(context.locale, ['common', 'plp'])),
        userAuthToken,
        menuCategories,
        productList,
        checkoutConfig,
      },
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error('[Error]:', error?.message)
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
}

export default ProductListPage
```

**Hook**

useFilerOptions.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    const queryParams = getUrlParams()
    const formQuery = queryParams !== '' ? `&${getUrlParams()}` : ''
    const formSearchQuery = queryParams !== '' ? `${getUrlParams()}` : ''

    const variables = {
      countryCode,
      languageCode,
      page: pageNumber, // Page number starts from 0
      count: PRODUCT_COUNT,
      queryParam: isSearch ? formSearchQuery : formQuery,
      gender: genderParam,
    }

    if (!isSearch) {
      variables.urlPath = urlPath
    }
    fetchProductListData({ variables })
  }, [selectedOptions, getUrlParams])
```

Is there a way to not run the useEffect if there is data exist on server side, also I am saving the data in context when received from server.

I have tried putting a check inside useEffect for state and the context but it did not work properly.

Like below :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const queryParams = getUrlParams()
    const formQuery = queryParams !== '' ? `&${getUrlParams()}` : ''
    const formSearchQuery = queryParams !== '' ? `${getUrlParams()}` : ''

    const variables = {
      countryCode,
      languageCode,
      page: pageNumber, // Page number starts from 0
      count: PRODUCT_COUNT,
      queryParam: isSearch ? formSearchQuery : formQuery,
      gender: genderParam,
    }

    if (!isSearch) {
      variables.urlPath = urlPath
    }
    //console.log(productListData?.length)
    if (productListData !== undefined && selectedOptions?.length > 0) {
      fetchProductListData({ variables })
    }
  }, [selectedOptions, getUrlParams])
```

I am expecting useEffect not to run on page load if there is already data in the context after page is rendered on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make first load detecting by the useRef hook. Put it inside the component where your useEffect hook is placed.

```
const firstLoad = useRef(true);
```

Then add the following to your useEffect:

```
if (firstLoad.current && productListData?.length > 0) {
  firstLoad.current = false;
  return;
}
```

The final useEffect code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const queryParams = getUrlParams()
    const formQuery = queryParams !== '' ? `&${getUrlParams()}` : ''
    const formSearchQuery = queryParams !== '' ? `${getUrlParams()}` : ''

    if (firstLoad.current && productListData?.length > 0) {
      firstLoad.current = false;
      return;
    }

    const variables = {
      countryCode,
      languageCode,
      page: pageNumber, // Page number starts from 0
      count: PRODUCT_COUNT,
      queryParam: isSearch ? formSearchQuery : formQuery,
      gender: genderParam,
    }

    if (!isSearch) {
      variables.urlPath = urlPath
    }
    fetchProductListData({ variables })
  }, [selectedOptions, getUrlParams])
```

This way you check if the initial productListData has any items in the first useEffect trigger (on page load). If the array isn't empty, data fetching (fetchProductListData) will be skipped. If there are no items in the array, the fetchProductListData function will be triggered.